# how to make context rotate on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the context inside the canvas to rotate on button click, I'm pretty sure that I have to use `onclick`, but I don't know where to put it or what logic do I have to write inside it. Can anyone help me out?

I tried using jquery on click but that does not work:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInp" onchange="readImage(this)">
<button type="button" class="rotate">Rotate</button>
<div>
<canvas id="canvasImg" style="max-width:100%; border:solid;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function readImage(input) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasImg');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (input.value !== '') {
        imgSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = imgSrc;
}

jQuery('.rotate').on('click', function() {
    degree = 90;
    drawRotate(degree);
})

function drawRotate(degree) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    context.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.width / 2);
    context.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so there are a few problems in your code..

1. in the drawRotate function you use variables such as `image`, `context`, `canvas` which is never has declared..
2. you call the function param `degree` but use it as `degreeS`
3. you translate the context forward, but never return him back
4. maybe there was more and i forget..

shortly, please look at the attached code

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInp" onchange="readImage(this)">
<button type="button" class="rotate" onclick="drawRotate(90)">Rotate</button>
<div>
    <canvas id="canvasImg" style="max-width:100%; border:solid;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasImg');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const input = document.getElementById('fileInp');

    function readImage(input) {

        context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let imgSrc;
        if (input.value !== '') {
            imgSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);
            context.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
        }
        img.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function drawRotate(degree) {

        let imgSrc;
        if (input.value !== '') {
            imgSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.rotate(degree * Math.PI / 180);
            context.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);
            context.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);

        }
        img.src = imgSrc;

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

play around `rotate(-180deg)` for continous rotation

```js
function readImage(input) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasImg');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (input.value !== '') {
        imgSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = imgSrc;
}

jQuery('.rotate').on('click', function() {
    $("#canvasImg").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
})

function drawRotate(degree) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    context.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.width / 2);
    context.restore();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="fileInp" onchange="readImage(this)">
<button type="button" class="rotate">Rotate</button>
<div>
<canvas id="canvasImg" style="max-width:100%; border:solid;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't css transofmr only rotate the image but not canvas?